# Android: LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates doesn't respect params

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps

I have a problem recieving notifications from LocationManager after a set period of time:

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(useGPS) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 999999, 
                999999, locationListener);
```

In emulator my location listener's onLocationChanged method gets called whenever I send a fix via emulator control (i.e. every other second)
So, the question is - is this because the way I'm testing on emulator, or LocationManager doesn't respect params?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc says:

minTime - the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. **This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.**

Comment: I see, but actual interval differs too much. The gap between 1 second and 999 seconds is too big in fact. And I'm trying to understand the reason for this